# PDO fetch assoc when joining tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

fetching an assoc-array with PDO seems to not show all resulting columns when joining tables.

```
<?php
$stmt = $GLOBALS['db']->prepare("
SELECT * 
  FROM printer
     , printermanufacturer
     , printermodel
     , colorprofile
     , papersize 
 WHERE User = :userID 
   AND printer.Manufacturer = printermanufacturer.ID 
   AND printer.Model = printermodel.ID 
   AND printer.Colorprofile = colorprofile.ID 
   AND printer.papersize = papersize.ID
");

$stmt->bindValue(':userID', $userID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

This should result in an associative array with e.g. `printermanufacturer.Name` and `printermodel.Name`, but it doesn't. There is only one row called Name.
Is there a solution without renaming each and every column like `SELECT` `printermanufacturer.Name AS pmName` ...

Thanks

edit: In the duplicate question there was also the (unanswered) question about:
"is there a way to automatically have the t2 columns be identified as t2.col1, t2.col2, (etc)"
Is this possible?

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992. Come. JOIN us. And no. Always select the columns you actually want.

Comment: I never wrote queries like this and then I saw this girl at my workplace doing queries like this. I didn't even know it was possible until a week ago. I wonder where she learned it

Comment: I prefer to use post-1992 `JOIN` syntax because it puts the join conditions closer to the respective join. If you use the old 1989 "comma-style" join syntax, you have to hunt through the WHERE clause to figure out which conditions pertain to each join. Some brands of SQL databases took years to implement the 1992 standard syntax, and examples were still written using the old syntax for years after that, even to the current day.

Comment: I learned it like this many years ago. Never had problems with this syntax. I would prefer a auto-join-feature: SELECT x,y,z from tabl1, tabl2 AUTOJOIN depending on foreign key conditions of the database. This would make life much easier. But it that syntax is really not used any more... I'll use JOIN. But I dont see a big advantage.

Answer (score 0):

[PDO::FETCH_NAMED](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) should help

> PDO::FETCH_NAMED: returns an array with the same form as PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, except that if there are multiple columns with the same name, the value referred to by that key will be an array of all the values in the row that had that column name